# How can I correctly take the sum of a subset in a Pandas time series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this time series (`raw_series`):

```
2016-03-30 00:01:00    2
2016-03-30 04:54:00    4
2016-03-30 08:51:00    1
2016-03-30 08:54:00    0
2016-03-30 08:55:00    1
2016-03-30 08:56:00    1
2016-03-30 08:57:00    2
2016-03-30 08:58:00    0
2016-03-30 09:00:00    1
2016-03-30 09:01:00    0
2016-03-30 09:04:00    0
2016-03-30 09:05:00    7
2016-03-30 09:06:00    4
2016-03-30 09:22:00    0
2016-03-30 09:24:00    8
2016-03-30 09:25:00    3
2016-03-30 09:28:00    0
2016-03-30 09:29:00    0
2016-03-30 09:39:00    1
2016-03-30 09:40:00    1
2016-03-30 09:41:00    1
```

I want to calculate the sum of the values at 09:00 and at 08:00. This is what I do (but won't work)

```
now = datetime.now()
try:
    this_hour = raw_series[datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour)].sum()
except KeyError:
    this_hour = 0

prev = now - timedelta(hours=1)
try:
    prev_hour = raw_series[datetime(prev.year, prev.month, prev.day, prev.hour)].sum()
except KeyError:
    prev_hour = 0
```

The time I was running the program `now` was (copied from the debug output file):

```
[30/Mar/2016 09:59:45] DEBUG [main.views:267] now is 2016-03-30 09:59:41.318779
```

The resulsts are: `this_hour = 1.0` and `prev_hour = 0` (exception)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you could convert your index to `datetime.index` with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM3_O07ufLAhWDWSwKHZ7-DHEQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.to_datetime.html&usg=AFQjCNHM8s9sToYu7_TRwFWJ1UK_WW_L4g&sig2=dkSP9kZ21l8b-yI2StA33A&bvm=bv.118353311,bs.2,d.bGQ) and then use mask for hours:

```
s = pd.Series([2, 4, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 8, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], index=['2016-03-30 00:01:00', '2016-03-30 04:54:00', '2016-03-30 08:51:00', '2016-03-30 08:54:00', '2016-03-30 08:55:00', '2016-03-30 08:56:00', '2016-03-30 08:57:00', '2016-03-30 08:58:00', '2016-03-30 09:00:00', '2016-03-30 09:01:00', '2016-03-30 09:04:00', '2016-03-30 09:05:00', '2016-03-30 09:06:00', '2016-03-30 09:22:00', '2016-03-30 09:24:00', '2016-03-30 09:25:00', '2016-03-30 09:28:00', '2016-03-30 09:29:00', '2016-03-30 09:39:00', '2016-03-30 09:40:00', '2016-03-30 09:41:00'])

s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index)
cur_hour = 9
prev_hour = cur_hour - 1
res1 = s[s.index.hour == cur_hour].sum()
res2 = s[s.index.hour == prev_hour].sum()

In [57]: res1
Out[57]: 26

In [58]: res2
Out[58]: 5
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. However I still don't understand why my approach is not giving the expected result.

Comment: Because for datetime slicing you'll get results when your minutes is zero, for first case it'll be `2016-03-30 09:00:00` for second nothing. You could check that with `now = datetime(year=2016, month=3,day=30, hour=9); s[now:now]`